# SELECT MAX(column) returning only column name

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This has got me all confused! I'm trying to return the max value from a column in my database but the return value is always the name of the column.

The query I use:

```
private static final String SELECTMAX = "SELECT MAX(?) FROM " + TABLE_NAME ;
```

The (test) function to return the max value:

```
public int getMaxValue(String field){

   int r = 0;
   String f[] = new String[] {field};
   Cursor c = this.db.rawQuery(SELECTMAX, f);
   if (c.moveToFirst()) {
       String s = c.getString(0);
       Log.i("XXXXX","Max num: " + s); 
   }
   return r;
}
```

The column i'm querying is an INTEGER type but the result 's' is always the column name and not the desired value.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have much experience in sqllite, is ? a parameter of a prepared statments? If so it looks like you are selecting the max of the string representation of your column name, you shouldn't pass the column name as a parameter.

So your query should look like.

`SELECT MAX(s) FROM " + TABLE_NAME;`

You are effectively executing

`SELECT MAX('s') FROM " + TABLE_NAME;`

Comment: +1 This is almost certainly it.  If you want to conform Chris's answer you could change the code so that f is some other arbitrary string e.g. "Chris is right"

Comment: No, this is definitely it. Why would I change f to an arbitrary string?

Comment: If you r sure it is right, there is no need to change it to an arbitrary string.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of the [DatabaseUtils](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html).stringForQuery() static method that is already in Android SDK to easily retrieve a value, this example is for `String` bot there is also method for `Long`

```
stringForQuery(SQLiteDatabase db, String query, String[] selectionArgs)
```

Utility method to run the query on the db and return the value in the first column of the first row.

Something like

```
String myString=DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery(getDB(),query,selectionArgs);
```

Comment: Thanks, hadn't come across that class yet. Looks like it could help a lot :)